# After deleting IIS site all other sites on the server loose certificate binding

Tags: c#, iis

Im using Microsoft.Web.Administration to add and remove websites in IIS, but when i delete a website all the other sites loose their certificate binding on https bindings (All use the same certificate).

Code used to delete the site ( It gives no errors, and correctly cleans up the site):

```
readonly ServerManager gSrvMngr= new ServerManager();

public bool DeleteSite(string siteName)
{
    bool foundSite = false; ;
    foreach (Site site in gSrvMngr.Sites)
    {
        if (site.Name != siteName)
            continue;

        site.Stop();
        gSrvMngr.Sites.Remove(site);
        foundSite = true;
        break;
    }

    foreach (var appPool in gSrvMngr.ApplicationPools)
    {
            if (appPool.Name != siteName)
                    continue;

        gSrvMngr.ApplicationPools.Remove(appPool);
        foundSite = true;
        break;
    }

    if(foundSite)
        gSrvMngr.CommitChanges();

    return foundSite;
}
```

Comment: Are they using different application pools or are all sites in the same application pool?

Comment: All sites have their own application pool ( With a matching name to the site).